# onChange method with "f.input collection" in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, collections

I have this dropdown:

```
<%= f.input :window_type, collection: @window, selected: @window.first, label: "Window Type", input_html: {onChange: "changePlaceholder(this)", type: "text"} %>
```

I want to capture when you change an option there, so i can change a placeholder with javascript. So i made this function to check that i was receiving the expected value:

```
function changePlaceholder(this){
  console.log("This is " + JSON.stringify(this));
}
```

But when i try to run it, it gives an error with the "this" variable, it says unexpected token. Before i had to change the C from onChange to caps because it was not like that so maybe i'm missing something else with the "this".

I could use a select_chosen, but i prefer the f.input so i can have control over the parameter name in the controller. Thanks.

Comment: looks like 'this' isn't a json object so you can't call stringify on it, can you log this and see what you get?

Comment: i also thought about this but same error. I guess if that was the error it would say something about this not being a json or something.

Comment: what does console.log(this) show ?

Comment: It's not being executed since the parameter is giving the error of unexpected token.

Answer (score 1):

At the end the answer was simple, something like this works. You have to add a class to the input like:

```
<%= f.input :topic1, collection: @inputs,include_blank: false,label: "First Input To Read From (Referenced as F)",input_html: {class: "topic1", type: "text" } %>
```

And then, with jquery:

```
$(document).on("change", "select.topic1", function(e){
  var topic1 = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
}
```